# Drawing topology of network with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, diagrams

I want to draw with Tikz a topology as illustrated below
[image]

The shape of node preferred is ball, can you help me ?

[image]

Comment: @cfr, can you help me?

Comment: As this is your 4th question with an answer which seems to solve your problem, you should consider accepting them (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). Furthermore you can thank the people by upvoting the answers (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't hugely difficult, and the pictures use nothing that isn't obviously in the manual:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{ball/.style={shape=circle, shading=ball, ball color=blue!50!cyan!50,
  minimum size=0.375cm}}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw circle [radius=1];
\foreach \i in {0,...,7}
   \node [ball] (n-\i) at (\i*45:1) {};
\foreach \i [evaluate={\j=int(\i+4);}] in {0,...,3}
   \draw (n-\i) -- (n-\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\[1em]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw grid (2, 2);
\foreach \i in {0,...,2}\foreach \j in {0,...,2}
    \node [ball] (n-\i-\j) at (\j, \i) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\\[1em]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw grid (2, 2);
\draw [shift={(0, 0, 1)}] grid (2, 2);
\foreach \i in {0,...,2}\foreach \j in {0,...,2}\foreach \k in {0,1}
   \node [ball] (n-\i-\j-\k) at (\j, \i, \k) {};
\foreach \i in {0,...,2}\foreach \j in {0,...,2}
  \draw (n-\i-\j-0) -- (n-\i-\j-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]